# UWP: How to assign a LayerVisual as the first child of a Panel

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-composition-api

I am adding a `LayerVisual` to a `Panel` by invoking

```
LayerVisual layerVisual; // this is created using a Compositor in previous logic
Panel parent; // I get this Panel from my XAML
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(parent, layerVisual);
```

Unfortunately using `ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual()` I have two problems:

1. I can set only one `LayerVisual` at a time
2. such `LayerVisual` is placed on top of all the other elements (and I want instead it in the background)

Therefore, I would be happy to have a solution like

```
parent.Children.Insert(0, layerVisual);
```

but unfortunately the `layerVisual` is not an `UIElement`.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: I only see that you can add children to `layerVisual`. What's the effect that you want?

Comment: I want to add low level DropShadow to elements contained in a Canvas. For internal  reasons I cannot use the DropShadowPanel provided by the UWP Toolkit.

Comment: Have you checked the [Win2D Effect](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)?

Comment: Thank you Timo for the hint, could you be a little bit more specific please? which effect are you referring to?

Comment: The [ShadowEffect](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_ShadowEffect.htm).

Comment: Thank you Timo. Following your link, I can see there is a caveat: "Supported by Win2D but not Windows.UI.Composition.". Since we are using in several cases the Composition API, how can we deal with this dichotomy? Moreover, is there anyway a chance to set several LayerVisual elements as children of a Panel?